# My to_string() function is not working and I don't know why

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int x);    

int main(){

    int num;

    cout << "Enter a number: "; cin >> num;

    isPalindrome(num);

    return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(int x){
    string str = to_string(x);
    string str2 = str;
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    if(str == str2){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run my program it gives me the following error. My compiler (g++) is up to date so I don't know why it's not letting me compile this. I've tried everything but nothing works. I even changed the standard for my C++ in Visual Studio Code but it still gives me this error. On the other hand it works for other people who try and run it and I don't know why. I looked at multiple YouTube videos, uninstalled Mingw and reinstalled it, checked my version on the cmd (which is 9.2.0) and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to solve this?

````
palindrome_Leetcode.cpp:21:29: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
     string str = to_string(x);```
````

Comment: `-std=c++14` -- Did you add that to the command-line when you compiled your code?

Comment: OT: `if(str == str2){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }` can be replaced with `return (str == str2);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *`-std=c++11`

Comment: Are you sure you're using GCC 9? Maybe you have more than one version installed? Because GCC 9 should be using C++11 by default, without needing a flag. Apparently C++98 was the default mode in GCC 5 and earlier.